# Apache - suppress the nececity to provide the .exe extension on using cgi with executables

Tags: windows, apache

I have some program that is meant to be integrated into a webserver and comes with some docs and scripts. the main executable is a binary that is supposed to be used via CGI.
However - the websites only reference the program with its name without the "exe"-extension.

How can i configure Apache to search for matching executables if no extension is provided in the URL (e.g. as windows does there running a program does not require the .bat or .exe extension to be specified)

Comment: You want to implement an internal request rewriting. Take a look at the documentation of the http servers rewriting module for that. It is of excellent quality and comes with good examples: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: @arkascha It does not look like that i am searching for. As far as i understand it i could use this if i set up one rule for every executable. but i am looking for a more generic approach, there the webserver tries to match default extensions (in a certain priority) to the given filename. So if 'interpreter' is requested it should look for 'interpreter.exe' and if not present for 'interpreter.bat' ... until all default extensions were tried.

Comment: `RewriteRules` are based on regular patterns which allow to match generic path patterns and extract tokens from it. They are _the_ standard means for what you want to do.

Comment: Apart from that I wonder if what you describe in your last statement is such a good idea: to execute anything that might match a given request. Such approaches typically lead to security issues.

Comment: @arkascha since the execution is limited to the cgi-bin directory every thing could be executed if the name is known. Just adding or not adding the file extension does not change much. Also this is an internal Develop/Test tool without access from the outside

Comment: The difference is that a request to a non existing resource might suddenly trigger some action which you did not expect or overlooked. Not necessarily harmful, sure. But rubber like features trying to be unbelievable smart and grant everything typically cause surprises. Just my personal experience.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments internal rewriting the request will offer what you are looking for. Take a look at this primitive example:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/cgi-bin/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}.exe -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.exe [END]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/cgi-bin/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}.bat -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.bat [END]
```

An alternate approach would be something like that:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}.exe -f
RewriteRule ^/cgi-bin/([a-z0-9_]+)$ /cgi-bin/$1.exe [END,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}.bat -f
RewriteRule ^/cgi-bin/([a-z0-9_]+)$ /cgi-bin/$1.bat [END,NC]
```

Best is to place such rules in the http servers host configuration. That is precise, fast and easy to debug. An alternative would be Apache famous "dynamic configuration files" (`.htaccess` files), but those can cause a lot of issues and does not offer any advantage in your situation.

Comment: okay, i see i overlooked the `-f` conditionals. I found something called "Multiview" by adding `+MultiViews` (or better spoken by replacing the Minus-Sign) it also seems to work. Are there any downsides on this?

Comment: The general recommendation these days is to switch off the `MultiViews` feature, since it often causes very surprising side effects when combined with other features. But if it serves your desired purpose, sure, go ahead.

Comment: hmm - it seems that the multiviews only works for the bat files. the .exe is not executed but downloaded.  But none of your two suggestions seem to work - i always get an 'object not found'

Comment: Hm, that surprises, we will have to fine out what detail we overlooked... I suspect the rules are _not_ applied at all, otherwise I would expect other error messages. So could you please check that? Place a definite syntax error in that rule set and repeat a request. You should get an internal error (http status 500) and a corresponding entry in your http servers error log file. If that is _not_ the case, then your rules are not applied at all.

Comment: The rules are evaluated. using invalid regex causes the apache not to start. I think the problem is that the server requested urls does not match the file system structure (`ScriptAlias`) and the doc and script dirs are outside the server-root - beside this, th `%{REQUEST_URI}` seems also to contain the url-parameter string.

But i found the issue with the downloading of the .exe. By default its mime type is `application/x-msdownload`. with `AddHandler  cgi-script .exe` this can be overridden in the directory directive. so enabeling MultiViews seems to work for both.

Comment: As the documentation shows: `%{ REQUEST_URI}` The path component of the requested URI. That does not include the query string. Also it is irrelevant if the script folder is inside the DocumentRoot (it should never be!) or whether you use some Alias directive: the rewriting process is executed _before_ any such directives apply. So the question is why those rules do not match your requests. For that I would have to get a view on how you integrated them into your host configuration.

Comment: on my test batch-cgi script that outputs environment variables the `REQUEST_URI` includes the parameters. may be the env-var differs from the one that are passed to the `mod_rewrite` directives. but since it is now working as desired i will go with this. As stated it is only for internal development.